# bootstrap button shows blue outline when clicked

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I added this but still the blue outline appear when the button is clicked.

```
.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

how to remove that ugly thingy?

Comment: try to set `:active` for the button. Additional: **Use the Inspector** in your browser to find the Problem.

Comment: Can you post your bit more code or jsfiddle demo so that we can help you

Comment: Not sure about buttons but bootstrap adds box-shadow to input fields which can be removed with

    box-shadow:none;

Comment: FWIW, the focus styling is important for keyboard navigation.

Comment: A picture would be useful here

Comment: keep scrolling until you reach @Janak answer

Answer (score 272):

May be your properties are getting overridden.
Try attaching  `!important` to your code along with the :active .

```
.btn:focus,.btn:active {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Also add box-shadow because otherwise you will still see the shadow around button.

Although this isn't a good practise to use !important I suggest you use more specific class and then try applying the css with the use of !important...

Comment: @Janak But why is it necessary when overriding the :active?

Comment: I may also add that when nuking with !important, the pseudo-classes aren't necessary

Comment: If you're using Bootstrap 4, add `box-shadow: none` (and don't forgot the prefix `-webkit-box-shadow: none`) to this answer. Also note that Bootstrap 4 already has `.btn:focus { outline: none }` in its btn classes.

Comment: Visual cues are critical when not navigating with a mouse. If you remove the outline you must add some other visual feedback, or you will have crippled your site.

Answer (score 125):

There are built-in boostrap class `shadow-none` for disabling `box-shadow` (not `outline`) (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/shadows/). This removes shadow of button:

```
<button class='btn btn-primary shadow-none'>Example button</button>
```

**Update**: docs link for bootstrap 5: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/utilities/shadows/, and for beta: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/shadows/

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: This IS the solution you're looking for. This is the solution, move along, move along. Thanks this solved it for Firefox with Bootstrap 4.

Comment: This post is about removing the outline, not the shadow. So sadly, this comment is misleading.

Comment: Yes, it was the best answer but why it is not accepted on Alert Dismissing cross button

Comment: Does not work. The CSS solution from the other answers work.

Comment: It helped me indirectly. I named my class as btn-primary which is also a bootstrap class which is causing problem.

Answer (score 63):

In the latest version of Bootstrap, I found removing outline itself doesn't work. And I have to add this because there is also a box-shadow:

```
.btn:focus, .btn:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: This is what helped for me.

Comment: If you want to make sure you're hitting all of your buttons, just use button { outline: none !important; box-shadow: none !important; }

Answer (score 22):

**Try Below Code**

```
.button:active, 
 button:active,
.button:focus, 
 button:focus,
.button:hover, 
 button:hover{
    border:none !important;
    outline:none !important;
}
```

Comment: I only needed this part to remove the outline in chrome: button:focus {outline:none;}

Answer (score 13):

This was happening to me in Chrome (though not in Firefox). I've found out that the `outline` property was being set by Bootstrap as `outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;`. Solved by overriding the `outline` property later in my custom CSS as follows:

```
.btn.active.focus, .btn.active:focus, .btn.focus, .btn:active.focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

this will solve button with a text, button only a icon or a button is a link:

```
 <!--1. button with a text -->
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="newWord">Save</button>

 <!--2. button only with a close icon -->
 <button type="button" class="close"></button>

 <!--3. button is a link -->
 <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs" href="#">Save</a>



button,
button:active,
button:focus, 
button:hover,
.btn,
.btn:active, 
.btn:focus, 
.btn:hover{   
    outline:none !important;
}
```

if you add `border:none !important;`

```
{
    border:none !important;
    outline:none !important;
}
```

then the button will become smaller size when clicked.

Answer (score 11):

In Bootstrap 4 they use
`box-shadow: 0 0 0 0px rgba(0,123,255,0);` on :focus, so i solved my problem with

```
a.active.focus,
a.active:focus,
a.focus,
a:active.focus,
a:active:focus,
a:focus,
button.active.focus,
button.active:focus,
button.focus,
button:active.focus,
button:active:focus,
button:focus,
.btn.active.focus,
.btn.active:focus,
.btn.focus,
.btn:active.focus,
.btn:active:focus,
.btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    outline-color: transparent;
    outline-width: 0;
    outline-style: none;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,123,255,0);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
.btn
{
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The SCSS way for all elements (not only buttons):

```
body {
  * {
    &:focus, &.focus,
    &:active, &.active {
      outline: transparent none 0 !important;
      box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,123,255,0) !important;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This may help if someone still has this question unresolved.

```js
(function() {
  $('button').on('click', function() {
    $("#action").html("button was clicked");
    console.log("the button was clicked");
  });
})();
```

```css
.btn-clear {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-style: none !important;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn-clear:active,
.btn-clear:focus {
  outline-style: none !important;
  outline-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- this button has default style -->
<button>Action</button>
<!-- this button is clear of style -->
<button class="btn-clear">Action</button>

<label id="action"></label>
```

Answer (score 4):

I just had the same issue and the following code worked for me:

```css
.btn:active, .btn:focus, .btn:active:focus, .btn.active:focus {
    outline: none !important;
}

.btn {
  margin:32px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->




<button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Button</button>
```

Hoping it will help!

Comment: outline!  doh!!  *thud*

Answer (score 3):

You need to use proper nesting and then apply styles to it.

- Right click on button and find the exact class nesting for it using (Inspect element using firebug for firefox), (inspect element for chrome).
- Add style to whole bunch of class. Only then it would work

Answer (score 3):

I found this quite useful in my case after the button click.

```
$('#buttonId').blur();
```

Answer (score 3):

I opted to simply remove the border width on `:focus`. This removes the ugly space between the outline and the button's rounded corners. For some reason this issue only happens on actual button elements and not `<a class="btn">` elements.

```
button.btn:focus {
  border-width: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes `{outline: 0}` didn't solve the problem and we can try `{box-shadow: none;}`

Answer (score 3):

Here's my Boostrap 4 solution to remove the button outline

```
/*
* Boostrap 4
* Remove blue outline from button
*/

.btn:focus,
.btn:active {
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually in bootstrap is defined all variables for all cases. In your case you just have to override default variable '$input-btn-focus-box-shadow' from '_variables.scss' file. Like so: 
`$input-btn-focus-box-shadow: none;`
Note that you need to override that variable in your own custom '_yourCusomVarsFile.scss'. And that file should be import in project in first order and then bootstrap like so:

```
@import "yourCusomVarsFile";
@import "bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "someOther";
```

The bootstraps vars goes with flag '!default'.

```
$input-focus-box-shadow: $input-btn-focus-box-shadow !default;
```

So in your file, you will override default values.
Here the illustration:

```
$input-focus-box-shadow: none;
$input-focus-box-shadow: $input-btn-focus-box-shadow !default;
```

The very first var have more priority then second one. The same is for the rest states and cases.
Hope it will help you.

Here is '_variable.scss' file from repo, where you can find all initials values from bootstrap: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/v4-dev/scss/_variables.scss

Chears

Answer (score 3):

Even after removing the outline from the button by setting its value to 0, There is still a funny behaviour on the button when clicked, its size shrinks a bit. So i came up with an optimal solution:

```
.btn:focus {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: 0 0 0 0;
}
```

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 3):

How to avoid border focus on click of bootstrap buttons:

```
.btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus, .btn-secondary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus, .show>.btn-secondary.dropdown-toggle:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
}

.btn.focus, .btn:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

How to avoid border focus on click of bootstrap input fields:

```
.form-control.focus, .form-control:focus {
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

If this doesn't work for your specific case, then I suggest you to open the inspector page, click on the selector tool (small arrow in a box in the top-left corner) click on the element you are trying to edit, then click again on the same element and look at the "Styles" tab to see what changes in terms of CSS... search something related to "focus" and you should be able to detect the code you have to overwrite in your CSS. Hope this is helpful.

Answer (score 2):

```
a:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

this works for me on BS3

Answer (score 2):

This one worked for me in Bootstrap 4:

`.btn {border-color: transparent;}`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
.btn-primary:focus { 
  box-shadow: none !important; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind, if you're button is inside of an anchor like:

```
<a href='some_link'>
    <button class='btn'>Button</button>
</a>
```

Adding the style to the button itself may not be enough, you may need to add the `a:focus, a:active { outline: none }` CSS rules where appropriate (this worked for me).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below

```
.bootstrap-select .dropdown-toggle:focus 
 {
          outline: 0 !important;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using bootstrap 4, you can use outline and box-shadow.

```
#buttonId {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Or if the button is inside an element like a div without back-ground, box-shadow is enough.

```
#buttonId {
     box-shadow: none;
}
```

Example: https://codepen.io/techednelson/pen/XRwgRB

Answer (score 1):

Override the exact bootstrap statements:

```css
.btn-primary.focus, .btn-primary:focus, .btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active:focus,.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active:focus,.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle:focus{
 box-shadow: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using version 4.3 or higher, your code will not work properly.
This is what I used. It worked for me.

```css
.btn:focus, .btn:active {
    outline: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: You're right. It doesn't work without -webkit-box-shadow: none !important; line.

Answer (score 1):

Instead to target on button class (**.btn**), here I target to **button** element itself and it works for me.

```
        button:focus {
          outline:none !important;
          box-shadow:none !important;
        }
```

And can use `shadow-none` class for input field

Answer (score 1):

You can add below answer to your _variable.scss file, no need to change the other outline or any thing. I'm sure this will work.

```
$btn-active-box-shadow: none !important;
```

Answer (score 1):

For Check box and radio buttons

```
.form-check-input:checked ,.form-check-input:focus,.form-check-input:active {
  outline: none !important;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0,123,255,0) !important;
      -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.btn:focus{
    box-shadow:none !important;
}
```

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">



<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a non-CSS method. Using JQuery, simply remove the "focus" class whenever the element is has been clicked.

`$(".btn").mousemove(function(element) {
    $(this).removeClass("focus");
});`

This method may cause the border to flash into existence and then back out briefly, which doesn't look bad in my opinion (it looks like part of the response when the button is clicked).

The reason I used .mousemove() is that .click() and .mouseup() both proved to be ineffective.

Comment: neh. add more javascript to defeat CSS isn't the best of practices. IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

Changing these values worked for me. I found it by looking at the Developer Tools of Chrome

```
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled).active,
.btn-primary:not(:disabled):not(.disabled):active,
.show>.btn-primary.dropdown-toggle {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: /*Change This*/;
    border-color: /*Change This*/;
}
```

This retains the shadow of the button too, it only changes the color of the button on-click.

Answer (score 0):

Change the Border Color back to Grey

```
.btn:focus,
.btn:active{
 border: 1px solid #ced4da !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.btn:focus,.btn:active {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation of what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Comment: Actually, WHen you click on a button it's being focused and active. So we are using .btn:focus, btn:active.

and we are removing the outline and box-shadow using none. and we are using !important because in bootstrap css file it's by default written to make outline in button. I hope it's the proper explanation.

Outline: An outline is a line that is drawn around elements (outside the borders) to make the element "stand out".

Answer (score -1):

very simple :

```
.btn {outline: none;}
```