# Bootstrap 3: Cannot remove outline from link

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Firstly here's the [link](http://isotopethemes.com/blue/index-issue.html)

When I click on the carousel's main panel there is a mysterious blue line appearing, it disappears after few seconds. I tried setting the outline to none but it did not work. The style codes from this pices of code which is bootstrap 3's default code:

```
a:focus {
  outline: thin dotted;
  outline: 5px auto -webkit-focus-ring-color;
  outline-offset: -2px;
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [bootstrap button shows blue outline when clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333231/bootstrap-button-shows-blue-outline-when-clicked)

Answer (score 2):

Add `text-decoration:none` to that `a:focus` rule (or create your own, correctly placed in your stylesheet) and you should be fine. Worked in dev tools.

Comment: worked nicely, thank you flairs.