# React Bootstrap on mobile: confusing focus styling

Tags: css, reactjs, progressive-web-apps, react-bootstrap

**THE PROBLEM:**

In my project, when I select and then unselect a button on mobile, it still remains dark because it's in focus and that's confusing:
[Screen recording](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qExze.gif)

Here's the deployed page: https://covid-19-mortality.netlify.com/

**WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:**

I would like to override the button focused styling so that it is intuitive that the button is in focus and not selected.

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

I have tried every solution in [bootstrap button shows blue outline when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333231/bootstrap-button-shows-blue-outline-when-clicked).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.btn:active {
   background: #fff !important;
   color: #343a40 !important;
 }
```

Comment: Sadly, it still remains focused in the same way https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-1bef6213c66e.gif

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I misunderstood your question, apparently on mobile view your button stays active, and you have applied some classes to active state. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you! It's better but it still goes back to "selected" styling after a split second: https://im4.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-4-c1cd47972bdc.gif