# How to change the outline of a dropdown button in vue?

Tags: vue.js, dropdown

there is a grey outline around the button occurs when the dropdown is clicked for the second time.

[image]

so far in css I have added this style properties:

```css
.dropdown ::v-deep .dropdown-toggle {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: none;
    &:after {
        display: none;
    }
    &:hover {
        background: green;
        color: white;
        border-color: transparent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's not a border-color but an actual outline? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline Use your browser devtools to be sure by inspecting the element.

Comment: I tried doing the inspect but even after adding outline:none it appears. https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/dropdown I have taken the dropdown example from here. If you see any of the example, first click the button/dropdown the dropdown list exapands. Until then there is no outline, but you click the dropdown button again to close the panel, there is an outline surrounding the button.

Comment: I achieved to remove it by targeting `dropdown-toggle:active` and with `box-shadow: none !important` as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23337989/8816585

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieved to remove it by targeting `.dropdown-toggle:active` and setting `box-shadow: none !important` as suggested in this answer: [bootstrap button shows blue outline when clicked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23333231/bootstrap-button-shows-blue-outline-when-clicked/23337989#23337989)

PS: add some [deep selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55368933/8816585) if needed.